# How to do compare and increment atomically?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, weak-references, lock-free

In my attempt to develope a thread-safe C++ weak pointer template class, I need to check a flag that indicating the object is still alive, if yes then increment the object's reference count and I need to do the both steps atomically.

I know the existance of intrinsics functions provided by the compiler, for instance _InterlockedCompareExchange() and _InterlockedIncrement(). But what I want is an interlockedCompareIncrement() function, is there an efficient way to simulate this intrinsic using other primitives, at least on the Windows x86 platform?

Comment: If this is on Windows, you should say so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that `value` is your flag variable. It should be declared `volatile`.

```
long curvalue;
long newvalue;

do
{
    curvalue = value;
    newvalue = curvalue + 1;
}
while( _InterlockedCompareExchange( &value, newvalue, curvalue ) != curvalue );
```

As you see you can generalize this to whatever kind of arithmetic you need by changing the operations that are applied to calculate `newvalue`.

If you want to compare two values at the same time, your best bet is to pack both values into a single variable, and then operate on that single variable. Since you're using a flag combined with a reference count, I'd recommend using the lowest bit of `value` as the 'alive' flag, and then increment/decrement by 2 at a time. This allows you to encode both the flag and the reference count into a single 32-bit variable.

Comment: It's seems what I am looking for, I will look deeper in it.

Comment: +1: I was looking for an atomic IncIfNot function. This is also possible to write with a loop and _InterlockedCompareExchange()!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your library to run on multiple CPU or multiple core machines you have to use the hardware support provided by the CPU.  Here are some references for you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set
http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=47498

Or you have to use locking mechanism provided by the OS.  Such as

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684841%28VS.85%29.aspx
or
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in C++, you can write your own assembly code.

Perhaps this is related to [Implement atomic increment using atomic swap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712863/implement-atomic-increment-using-atomic-swap)